# Wiring Ceiling Fan Remote, Two Dimmers

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I think this DIY wiring is a bit too much (I honestly didn't know the fan came with a remote unit when I bought it). I have a switch with separate fan and light dimmers already installed (one switches the fan off and on and adjusts the speed, one switches and dims the light). I got the fan/light to work, but the remote and dimmers aren't responding as they should.  It's a Casablanca Glen Arbor with a remote.

My ceiling has a green, white, red (hot for the light dimmer I suspect) and black (hot for the fan dimmer I suspect).

The remote receiver unit has white, yellow, blue and black.

The fan has green, white, blue and black.

What would be the ideal way to wire this?  Thank you!

Comment: In the case of separate fan and light wall switches, I'd hook up the ceiling fan without the remote.  Green, white, blue, black.

Comment: The remote that comes with the fan/light is not intended to be used with wall switch fan speed control/light dimmer. In fact the instructions that come with some models of remote state that attempting to use the remote with a wall dimmer will damage the remote permanently. If that has happened, you could wire the fan without the remote and just use the wall controls. If permanent damage has not occurred, you might be able to use the remote by setting the wall controls on max and just using the remote.

Comment: See http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110887/is-it-safe-to-use-a-fan-control-with-any-ceiling-fan-as-long-as-you-wire-it-prop

Comment: You can get wall dimmers that use a remote of their own.  Is there a reason you're attached to the remote on the fan?

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, your using 2 incompatible set ups: hardwired and remotes. they're designed to be exclusive of each other. Either remove the canopy controller and use as standard fan, or remove dimmers in the wall, and use the remote.

If you really want both, you'll need to either uses something like this [wonderful but pricy setup](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017OAWQ0) or [something like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001BARKJC).

Comment: I don't mind replacing the dimmers with normal switches (I was planning to keep them open anyway), but the wiring would still be tricky.  Just cap the red?

I really don't care if the dimmer switch works or not, to be honest.

Comment: What I mean is cap the red and use it as a one switch on/off. Right now I have the fan motor hot attached to the receiver, the light wire capped on the receiver and the light hot directly wired to the light to dim it...that works, but obviously it's not ideal for remote control operation!  

I thought my answer was to cap one of the main hots before I posted, but I wanted to make sure there were no better answers!

Comment: If you want the remote, buy blank plates, remove the dimmers and twist the dimmer wires at the box together. Cap them and all that.

You're basically taking the dimmers out of the equation and use just the remote. if you need wall control of any kind, use one of the solutions I posted, or the wall switch being off will turn your remote off.